# In what ways would Earth's landscape (with fauna and flora) be different if humanity had never affected it?

Tags: humans, earth-like, alternate-history

I'm rewording the original question as suggested, in an attempt to make it more specific.

We all know we humans affect our environment by building structures, leveling ground etc. but these changes are usually pretty obvious and visible.

As I want to create an alternative Earth world, I thought I could simply use a real map to describe the world; however, having some basic historic knowledge of my hometown, which is a coastal city, I know that it's not simply built around a river, but the river delta has been regulated during the city's development. It made me thinking, how close our current geography is to what it could be without us, and similarly, how whole nature would look if not being influenced by humanity.

I'm not asking to describe all the changes humanity has done, specifically, but for general processes that will help me to investigate specific regions and do a better job at trying to create an alternative history for them. Answers already given are good examples of what I expect and I wonder if there's more ways in which humanity changed the Earth.

An advice has been made by XandarTheZenon, that perhaps this question should be asked on History site. I agree and I might do that, but not before using all my options to make this question valid, since I already asked it here. I stand by this question, as I think understanding how humans affected their environment is the key to create rich, deep worlds and that could be a reason to allow this question to be more vague than others (although I have a feeling there are many questions on this site which introduce such world characteristics that lead to many more possible answers). The additional benefit to asking here is that it allows for more freedom in giving examples (for example, on history site it's less likely to introduce aliens, elves or magical beings in argumentation) as well as is more forgiving for factual inaccuracy and soft-science.

Here's two examples:

- global warming - people and domesticated animals produced greenhouse gases, which warmed the planet. Without humanity the Earth would be cooler [and with another civilization it could as well be hotter, but let's consider other civilizations outside of the scope of this question]
- domesticated animals - people changed the way animals evolved: sometimes indirectly [this could be considered the butterfly effect], and sometimes directly through intended manipulation. So without humanity not only wouldn't we see domesticated animals like dogs, but it's also possible we wouldn't see some "wild" animals like dingoes:

[Wikipedia: Dingo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dingo)

```
The dingo (Canis lupus dingo) is a wild dog found in Australia. Its exact ancestry
is debated, but dingoes are generally believed to be descended from semi-
domesticated dogs
```

Comment: This seems like it is just a simply history question. And a broad one at that. In what ways have humans changed the world? A lot. And this is wrong site to ask those kind of questions. Then again, this doesn't even have a question specifically stated in it. It could just as well be closed as unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I can see how you tried to constrain the question, however it's still incredibly broad. o.m.'s post is probably the closest you're going to get to an answer, I'm afraid.

Comment: I agree this question might be too broad. This is why I asked for general processes instead of detailed scenarios, but maybe I wasn't clear enough about it.

Comment: I think you should ask a similar question in history.se, if you really want to know

Comment: Writing is only about 5000 years old. I'm not sure how Humanity could have changed a whole lot in that period. Humans from now in a developmental respect are pretty much the same as those from 5000 years ago.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs I wrote "around the invention of writing or even much before" - in the first case even a small change would still mean the humanity could for example respect nature more or less and from answers you can conclude this would affect flora and fauna as well as a shape of some rivers etc.   But also it's not said what the change to humanity would be - let's say humans gain superpowers, that's a huge change that surely affects civilization and the changes it makes, so 5000 years is plenty of time.

Comment: Cool question but remains super broad.  HistorySE would close this question as it is speculative/alternate history so I'd stick with world building, you just need to narrow it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was watching a BBC history documentary about the Romans in Britain earlier today and words along the lines of

> History is not like science, when you change one variable in history the others don't stay the same. It's all linked, change anything and there's such a massive cascading effect that it's impossible to say what may have happened.

Here are a couple of the key aspects:

**Extermination of the mega-fauna**. This is still uncertain but it's considered likely that human hunters destabilised the populations and effectively exterminated a lot of these animals.

**Deforestation**. This is a bigger issue than previously mentioned. Not just Central Europe and the Near East but from Britain, which was solid forest, all the way across Russia.

*With just these two differences the world would be a place unrecognisable to us.*

but let's consider the way the things we affect, affect the world in their turn.

Elephants knock over trees, fewer elephants, more trees. 
Wild herbivores eat young shoots, also keeping down new trees, [fewer predators, fewer trees, more erosion](http://oregonstate.edu/ua/ncs/archives/2003/oct/scientists-wolves-helping-rebalance-yellowstone-ecosystem).
Beavers build dams, meaning more shallow lakes, lower speed flow on the rivers, less erosion, but we killed all the beavers and cut down the trees that would bind the banks, so even the rivers don't follow the courses they would without us.

A few other things we've done.
Draining the wetlands, this was even done by the Romans.
Extermination of predators, the Iberian Lynx is almost gone, the Eurasian Lion has been gone a long time. The Sabertooth Cat? Not known if this was humans. Marsupial Lion, believed to be humans.

Comment: The statement in the quote (paraphrase) denies the purpose of whole Worldbuilding site.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady, only alternate history questions, butterfly effect applies.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady, you've said it yourself in the question, but I think you've underestimated quite how much it applies.

Comment: Obviously the smallest change 5000 years ago could completely turn our world upside down. The point was not to deal with the butterfly effect but to gather information on the processes in which humans change the world. In the end, a writer doesn't need to present an accurately simulated world, he just needs to create a setting that is interesting for readers, and knowledge about such processes help. As for alternate history - there is such tag on this site. Also creating an alternative world is quite similar to creating an alternative history on the same world.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady, on top of the way humans affect the world directly, there are the ways in which the things we affect, affect the world. Elephants knock over trees, fewer elephants, more trees. Wild herbivores eat young shoots, also keeping down new trees, fewer predators, fewer trees. Beavers build dams, meaning more shallow lakes, lower speed flow on the rivers, less erosion, but we killed all the beavers and cut down the trees that would bind the banks, so even the rivers don't follow the courses they would without us.

Comment: I should edit some of this into the answer of course.

Comment: That's some nice points, it's appreciated.

Comment: Extermination of the mega-fauna: Actually, recent discoveries in ice core samples and the black mat layer in North America, Europe, northern Africa and the Middle East led to the Younger Dryas impact hypothesis. This hypothesis states that about 13k years ago a meteorite impact was the main reason for the extermination of 75% of North America's mega-fauna. Humans? Not so much.

Comment: @OttoAbnormalverbraucher, I've not heard about that, do you have (publicly accessible) sources?

Comment: Not actual scientific ones but you can always google for Younger Drias impact hypothesis. There is at least a Wikipedia article. There is debate on whether this hypothesis could be true as the megafauna in NA, SA and Eurasia went extinct with a time lapse of a few hundred years but humans? Newest estimates say we arrived in America some time between 16k-20k years ago with about 1-10 Million humans living in the whole world.

Comment: I suspect the majority lived in Africa and Eurasia up until only a few thousand years ago so, how did a few thousand to a few Million people kill millions (???) of gigantic animals in only a few thousand years (if even) with nothing but hunter-gatherer tools and weapons? I don't think that adds up at all.

Comment: @OttoAbnormalverbraucher, it's an interesting theory, though I have to admit I don't think I've seen Wikipedia be as damning of a hypothesis as it is of that one. Even if true it only explains North American megafauna extinction, not global.

Answer (score 6):

[Deforestation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deforestation_during_the_Roman_period) is a big issue. Not just in the Mediterranean but also in central Europe.

[Monoculture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoculture) is another issue.

Unnatural selection through animal [husbandry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_husbandry).

Removal of other [apex predators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apex_predator).

While a civilization might try to be careful and environmentally conscious, humans would leave their mark -- killing other predators, growing more efficient food.

Answer (score 2):

Not just deforestation, but also de-deforestation.  Before humans got the ability to fight wildfires (not all of which are started by humans), they burned out of control.  Now we can put them out or create firebreaks.

The other major change to the landscape, courtesy of humanity, are dams and other hydrological projects.

Comment: +1 I was missing the point about constructions and the influence on rivers like regulating river deltas.